# What other cut of meat can replace pork shank?

Tags: substitutions, pork

I have really been wanting to trying this recipe [Braised Pork Shanks with Mushroom Dumplings](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/aaron-mccargo-jr/braised-pork-shanks-with-mushroom-dumplings-recipe/index.html), but I have not been able to obtain pork shanks.

Can another cut of pork meat be used instead?  I was considering using pork shoulder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably get away with pork shoulder, although you will want to consider that the texture may not be what you want -- it may either have too much fat and connective tissue, or it may fall apart too much, depending on how long you braise it for. You will probably have to alter your cooking times, I'd imagine.

Pork hocks are somewhat similar in texture to the shank, so that a possibility.  Though you will probably run into the same availability problems.

It may take a small amount of modification, but your best bet may be to go with country-style ribs. They are tender and flavorful when braised, and are readily available in any grocery store.

Comment: If you do use a pork shoulder, I would recommend trying to get a bone-in roast.  Pork Shanks contain a good deal of collagen/gelatin  due to their bone.  You could also compensate for the lack of a bone by adding a pack of unflavored gelatin at the end of the cooking (a technique espoused by Cooks Illustrated in many recipes).

Answer (score 2):

I think lamb shanks could be used.

Whatever, that is an Atlantic recipe - so much salt!

Answer (score 0):

Pork shoulder should work. A picnic shoulder (with the skin still on it) would be better.